# Python Django, html

Tags: python, django

Есть html код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="ru">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>ProjectName</title>

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo" id="logotype">
    </header>  

{{middle_page}}

    <footer>
        <h4>Footer_text</h4>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Изображение и css файл нормально импортируются, но нужно, чтобы вместо {{middle_page}} вставлялся html код из другого файла. Что нужно поставить вместо ???, чтобы в конечном итоге вместо {{middle_page}} был html код из файла main.html, находящийся в каталоге static\html\main.html

Вот код из файла views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

middle_page = {
    'middle_page_main': ???
}

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=middle_page)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри `index.html` подключить нужный шаблон

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include